# Maven profiles management - disable profile in POM

Tags: maven, maven-3

Is there a way to disable an active profile in POM ?

Otherwise how could i manage such a configuration

```
parentPOM
   |-- Parent Flex app POM
       |-- flexApp1 POM
       |      |-- App1-services POM
       |      |-- App1-flex-client POM
       |-- flexApp2 POM
              |-- App2-services POM
              |-- App2-flex-client POM
```

I have defined an Integration test profile on `Parent Flex app POM` which specify flex automation dependencies (much be included in the swf packaging for (and only for) integration testing.
Problem is that each flex app is composed of 2 module, a flex one and a java one. Of course i don't want to package flex automation lib into java module artifacts.

Proper way should be to trigger profile activation like this :

```
<activation>
    <property>
           <name>integrationTest</name>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>packaging</name>
        <value>swf</value>
    </property>
 </activation>
```

But : 
maven 3 does not support multiple activation properties (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-3328) neither than multiple condition with and operator (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4565).

So i though about a workaround by explicitly disabling profile in pure java modules' pom. But i didn't find a way to do it.

I would like to avoid to integrate maven extensions.

Please don't tell me to switch to gradle.

Comment: Why do you need a profile for integration tests ? Maven has a life-cycle-phase with **pre-integration-test, integration-test**?

Comment: Pre-integration-test goal is just here to launch a container, integration test to run the tests, my aim is to trigger conditional dependencies packaging according to deployment target (continuous integration server in this case)

Comment: If you have different dependencies you need having different integration tests modules (separate maven modules) to solve such things.

Comment: I don't think so, profile is designed for this kind of requirement, it just fails at activation configuration, the way i choose (and i think, the only way to go, at least using profiles) is to duplicate profile in all flex modules leaves. I let the question opened anyway cause this solution doesn't satisfy me

Comment: Exactly as you described. It fails based on activation of configuration. Furthermore you can't have different dependencies in the same module neither two profiles active which will use different dependencies.